# Bash - Passing the wrong value to the function

Tags: bash, shell

So, writing a bash script see the below code.

```
allAccessLocations=("/var/www/vhosts/*/logs/access_log" "/var/www/vhosts/*/statistics/access_log" "/var/log/httpd/access_log" "/var/log/httpd/access.log")

checkAccessPaths() {
    for i in ${allAccessLocations[*]};do
        let loopCount++
        local count=$(ls 2>/dev/null $i | wc -l)
        if (( $count > 0 ));then
            local toPass=${allAccessLocations[loopCount -1]}
            echo "this is what should be passed $toPass" >> $reportlog
            checkApacheIPTest $toPass
        else
            :
        fi
    done
}

checkApacheIPTest(){
    echo "echo $1 is what is passed" >> $reportlog
}
```

This is the below output from the log.

```
this is what should be passed /var/www/vhosts/*/logs/access_log 
echo /var/www/vhosts/website1/logs/access_log is what is passed

this is what should be passed /var/www/vhosts/*/statistics/access_log
echo /var/www/vhosts/*/statistics/access_log is what is passed
```

As you can see it KNOWS what to pass as a string to the next function, however when the directory path " /var/www/vhosts/*logs/access_log is passed to the next function, it automaticlly finds the first folder it can and the variable becomes that instead?

The idea is I'm trying to find out which path the Apache logs are in, as they can be in multiple location in different setups.

Comment: I suspect you just need to quote your variable when passing it to the function.

Comment: If you don't quote the variable, wildcards are expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes and `@`;

```
for i in "${allAccessLocations[@]}"; ...
```

Using the unquoted ${allAccessLocations[*]} is effectively the same as writing `for i in /var/www/vhosts/*/logs/access_log /var/www/vhosts/*/st ...`, and the * gets glob expanded.  Using @ and quotes effectivly expands the elements of the array and quotes each of them individually, preventing the glob expansion.

Comment: Also `"$toPass"` when calling the function.

Comment: Absolute geniues. I have been tearing my hair out for the past 3 hours at this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote `$toPass`. Otherwise, the wildcard in the variable is expanded, and `$1` will just be the first file that matches.

```
checkApacheIPTest "$toPass"
```

As a general rule you should always quote your variables unless you have a specific reason not to, because you want word splitting and wildcard expansion to be done on the result.